# How to use code blocks in embeds? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how to use code blocks in discord.py embeds.

Here's my code:
[image]

However, I want it to look something similar to this:
[image]

Comment: You can use backticks (`\`great code here\``) just like how you send a normal message (manually, on the Discord app/website, not using a bot) as code. You can also use three backticks (`\`\`\`great code here as a code block, usually when they're spread on more than one line\`\`\``); the same for the manual way too. How you format messages on the Discord platform is the same way you send messages using a bot. Just put the message (with the backticks etc.) in double/single quotes to make it a string.

Comment: If you want to see all the available styles for markdown cdeblocks on discord, I'd recommend checking out [this](https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51)

Comment: You can use triple backtick to make it code ```, and if you want color coding, discord has limited support for ansi (for example, try `print('\033[0;35m')`)

Answer (score 0):

Discord uses [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to add effects that can be used on text. To make code blocks, just wrap your text in backticks eg. `` `hello world` ``. If you want multi line code blocks, just wrap your text in triple backticks eg.

````
```
hello
world
```
````

This is not really a coding issue, it's more of a discord markdown issue.